# Variation to Ramanujan's infinite nested radical with primes

Tags: nested-radicals

Ramanujan's infinite nested radical states that
$$\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+4\sqrt{1+\cdots}}}}=3.$$

Now instead, consider the following infinite nested radical
$$\sqrt{1+p_1\sqrt{1+p_2\sqrt{1+p_3\sqrt{1+\cdots}}}}$$
where $p_n$ represents the $n$-th prime. How to solve this infinite nested radical?

Comment: There is no reason to believe there is a closed form for this.

Comment: The limit is near 3.22568498344851051856982775582317685533646416143213032426502169860927386459508390331119659768856929195159856682320561985158638328820199852394889053547987785793846478974996979088874003139014155342428713640693462247154958736855855470365471911538525967656663540343097162017154067171624676290223851165722937350851664632701780796912864265789241498492714034021555834084999829017955370529051821851669929889207597 if this helps...

Comment: Out of curiosity how did you get that Raymond?

Comment: @Ian Miller: Well a short [pari/gp](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/download.html) script : s=0;for(k=-2000,-1,s=sqrt(1+prime(-k)*s));s (to 400 digits with \p 400) or more nicely : f(m)=local(s=0);forstep(k=m,1,-1,s=sqrt(1+prime(k)*s));s