# A closed solution for $f^2[n]=1+nf[n+1]$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I attempted to solve $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{\cdots}}}}$ but it leads me to a recursive form  $f^2[n]=1+nf[n+1]$.

Is there a closed solution for this difference equation?

Comment: Apart from $f(n)=n+1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772688/) (Ramanujan's infinite nested radical) we have that 
$$
S = \sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+4\sqrt{1+\cdots}}}}=3.
$$

The correct recursive equation and its solution, for arriving at that result (3) is given here in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical#Ramanujan's_infinite_radicals).

So your expression is $\sqrt{1+S} = \sqrt{1+3} = 2$.